# Как сделать прокрутку с левой стороны?

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Как сделать, чтобы полоса прокрутки находилась не справа, а слева?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать `direction: rtl;` и не забыть поставить overflow `auto` или `scroll`. Для вложенного блока придётся переопределить обратно на `ltr`.

```css
html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}

main > * {
  direction: ltr;
}

div {
  height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>Как сделать, чтобы полоса прокрутки находилась не справа, а слева?</div>
</main>
```